# system encountered an unrecoverable error

Tags: 20.04

When I was adjusting the input method settings, the system froze. So, I forced a shutdown. After restarting and entering my password, I could only see the original Ubuntu wallpaper and the mouse cursor. After a few minutes, a message appeared saying that the system encountered an unrecoverable error."